# How to change .wav format audio file bitrate

Tags: c#, .net, audio, wav, naudio

In my application I have some .wav format audio files, here I check audio file bit rates by using **Naudio** dll, if bitrate is below 128kbps then I want to change it to above 128kpbs, so that I wrote below code for check bit rate, if it is less then 128kbps then it convert to above 128kbps.

```
int bitrate;
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(textBox1.Text))
{
    bitrate = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 8;
    reader.Dispose();
}

if (bitrate < 128000)
{
    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(textBox1.Text))
    {
     var newFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
        using (var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(newFormat, reader))
        {
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(@"C:\Docs\Files\", conversionStream);
        }
    }
}
```

For some files it is working fine, but for some files I am getting below error,

> An unhandled exception of type 'NAudio.MmException' occurred in NAudio.dll
>       Additional information: AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen

I am attaching error Snap here. Error [Error Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohos3.png)
Here, how can I slove this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). It is what I use for all audio/video conversion tasks.

It is a command-line tool that can convert from pretty much anything to anything, with lots of options. To do what you want, you will probably need to run something like:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.wav -ab 128 output.wav
```

In the above line, we convert the file to a 128 bitrate.

Easiest way to use this in code is to include the FFmpeg executable in your project (or install globally as an environment variable) and invoke it directly with something like:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";

process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i \"{originalFile}\" -ab 128 \"{outputPath}\"";

process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

There are more elegant solutions - wrappers around FFmpeg - but this should do the trick.

Comment: Hi @stoyan-berov, ffmpeg is look's awesome, but it is not suitable for requirment, here we have web application, So i want to convert that through programetically  only.  Thank you stoyan-berov.

Comment: Hey, I last used FFmpeg exactly for a web application - a .NET MVC project. With the code above (or similar) you do the conversion programatically only. Users do not see any consoles.

Answer (score 0):

`WaveFormatConversionStream` looks for an ACM codec that can perform the requested transformation. Not every transformation is possible. For example, you can't typically change sample rate, bit depth and channel count in one go. So the possible transformations depend on the exact `WaveFormat` of the incoming audio. You might need to downsample in one step, and go from stereo to mono in another. The `MediaFoundationResampler` is more flexible and might be able to do it in one step.